# Python: get a dict from a list based on something inside the dict

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I need to be able to find an item in a `list` (an item in this case being a `dict`) based on some value inside that `dict`.  The structure of the `list` I need to process looks like this:

```
[
    {
        'title': 'some value',
        'value': 123.4,
        'id': 'an id'
    },
    {
        'title': 'another title',
        'value': 567.8,
        'id': 'another id'
    },
    {
        'title': 'last title',
        'value': 901.2,
        'id': 'yet another id'
    }
]
```

*Caveats:* `title` and `value` can be any value (and the same), `id` would be unique.

I need to be able to get a `dict` from this `list` based on a unique `id`.  I know this can be done through the use of loops, but this seems cumbersome, and I have a feeling that there's an obvious method of doing this that I'm not seeing thanks to brain melt.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
my_item = next((item for item in my_list if item['id'] == my_unique_id), None)
```

This iterates through the list until it finds the first item matching `my_unique_id`, then stops. It doesn't store any intermediate lists in memory (by using a generator expression) or require an explicit loop. It sets `my_item` to `None` of no object is found. It's approximately the same as

```
for item in my_list:
    if item['id'] == my_unique_id:
        my_item = item
        break
else:
    my_item = None
```

`else` clauses on `for` loops are used when the loop is not ended by a `break` statement.

Comment: @agf What do you recommend when there are multiple matches and you want to extract them in a list(of matched dicts)?

Comment: @UGS If you need to scan the whole list and build up a result list, and not just find the first match, you can't do better than a list comprehension like `[item for item in my_list if item['id'] == my_unique_id]`.

Comment: This will not work for nested dict

Comment: @Umang can you give an example?

Answer (score 31):

If you have to do this multiple times, you should recreate a dictionnary indexed by id with your list :

```
keys = [item['id'] for item in initial_list]
new_dict = dict(zip(keys, initial_list)) 

>>>{
    'yet another id': {'id': 'yet another id', 'value': 901.20000000000005, 'title': 'last title'}, 
    'an id': {'id': 'an id', 'value': 123.40000000000001, 'title': 'some value'}, 
    'another id': {'id': 'another id', 'value': 567.79999999999995, 'title': 'another title'}
}
```

or in a one-liner way as suggested by agf :

```
new_dict = dict((item['id'], item) for item in initial_list)
```

Comment: `new_dict = dict((item['id'], item) for item in initial_list)`... why create an intermediate list then `zip`?

Answer (score 8):

I used this, since my colleagues are probably more able to understand what's going on when I do this compared to some other solutions provided here:

```
[item for item in item_list if item['id'] == my_unique_id][0]
```

And since it's used in a test, I think the extra memory usage isn't too big of a deal (but please correct me if I am wrong). There's only 8 items in the list in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Worked only with `iter()` for me:

```py
my_item = next(iter(item for item in my_list if item['id'] == my_unique_id), None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple function for this purpose:

```
lVals = [{'title': 'some value', 'value': 123.4,'id': 'an id'},
 {'title': 'another title', 'value': 567.8,'id': 'another id'},
 {'title': 'last title', 'value': 901.2, 'id': 'yet another id'}]

def get_by_id(vals, expId): return next(x for x in vals if x['id'] == expId)

get_by_id(lVals, 'an id')
>>> {'value': 123.4, 'title': 'some value', 'id': 'an id'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you want lookup search on the basis of the key of a dictionary.

`my_item = next((item for item in my_list if item.has_key(my_unique_key)), None)`

For 3.0+, `has_key()` has been deprecated. Instead use `in`:

`my_item = next((item for item in mylist if 'my_unique_key' in item), None)`

https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: test_list
Out[2]: 
[{'id': 'an id', 'title': 'some value', 'value': 123.40000000000001},
 {'id': 'another id', 'title': 'another title', 'value': 567.79999999999995},
 {'id': 'yet another id', 'title': 'last title', 'value': 901.20000000000005}]

In [3]: [d for d in test_list if d["id"] == "an id"]
Out[3]: [{'id': 'an id', 'title': 'some value', 'value': 123.40000000000001}]
```

Use list comprehension

Comment: This keeps going through the list after it has found a match.

Comment: If the ID should be unique, then doing a len() on this will show that you're getting non-unique IDs

Comment: It's not a matter of the ids maybe being non-unique -- it's the difference between doing an average of `len(my_list)` comparisons or `len(my_list) // 2` comparisons. Your version does twice as much work (on average) as is necessary.

Comment: Fair enough - although knowing when you have two matching IDs can be useful sometimes, I suppose set size also comes into play.

Comment: True -- but he told us the `id`s were unique as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a simple loop or . If you want to find an item based on a specific value , you can iterate over the list and check each dictionary's value . Here's how you can do it :

```
# Function to find item based on value
def find_item_by_value(data_list, value_to_find):
for item in data_list:
    if item['value'] == value_to_find:
        return item
return None

# Example usage
value_to_find = 567.8
found_item = find_item_by_value(data, value_to_find)
if found_item:
    print("Item found:", found_item)
else:
    print("Item not found")
```

This function find_item_by_value will return the first item it finds with the specified value. If no item is found , it returns None .