# How to get an object inside an array list by its property value in Python

Tags: python, list, object

I'm trying to write a `Sublime Text 2` plugin and get some value inside a `.subilme-settings` file.

```
{
"files":
    [
        {
            "name" : "Markdown",
            "extension" : ".md"
        },{
            "name" : "Python",
            "extension" : ".py"
        },{
            "name" : "Sublime Text Setting",
            "extension" : ".sublime-settings"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my first time with **Python** and I don't know how to do it, does exists something like:

```
my_array.indexOf({"extension":".py"})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python lists *do* have an `index` method. But it only finds values that are equal to the argument, not values that have an argument that matches your partial value.

There's really nothing in Python that finds partial-structure matches like this; you can search/filter/etc. on equality, or on a predicate function, but anything else you have to write yourself.

The easiest way to do this is with a loop. You can write it explicitly:

```
for index, element in enumerate(my_array):
    if element["extension"] == ".py":
        return index
```

… or in a comprehension:

```
return next(index for index, element in enumerate(array)
            if element["extension"] == ".py")
```

Alternatively, you can turn the matching into a function, and pass it to `filter`, or use it as a `key` function in a more complex higher-order function, but there doesn't seem to be any real advantage to that here.

And of course you can write your own `indexOf`-like function that matches partial structures if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to get the index:

```
>>> my_dict = {'files': [{'name': 'Markdown', 'extension': '.md'}, {'name': 'Python', 'extension': '.py'}, {'name': 'Sublime Text Setting', 'extension': '.sublime-settings'}]}
>>> def solve(key, val, lis):
        return next((i for i, d in enumerate(lis) if d[key] == val), None)
... 
>>> solve('extension', '.py', my_dict['files'])
1
```

Comment: Looks very similar to this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079241/python-get-a-dict-from-a-list-based-on-something-inside-the-dict

Comment: @bcollins The `next` and `enumerate` combo is very common, you can find it on tons of posts.

Answer (score 0):

This may very well not be the best solution, but you could try this:

```
i=0
for element in files:
    if '.py' in element:
        break
    else:
        i+=1
```

At the end of this loop, if it finds the extension you want, 'i' will be the index you're looking for. However, if you wanted a list of each element with an extension:

```
myElements=[]
for element in files:
    if '.py' in element:
        myElements.append(element)
```