# Display a product whose ID is passed as a parameter

Tags: python, django

I would like to retrieve the product whose 'id' is passed as a parameter, how do I do this?
For example here I passed the id equal to 1
Note I don't use a model but a dictionary

```
def cart_add(request, id):
  dico={"produits":[{'id':1,'name':'pomme de terre','price':1250}]}
  mes_produits=dico['produits']
  cart = Cart(request)
  mes_produits['id']=id
  product=mes_produits['id']
  cart.add(product=product)
  return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html')
```

i get this error : **list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: what line gives you that error?

Comment: this line : mes_produits['id']=id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: get a dict from a list based on something inside the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079241/python-get-a-dict-from-a-list-based-on-something-inside-the-dict)

Comment: mes_produits[0]['id']=id

Comment: I have this error : 'dict' object has no attribute 'id', this error come this line : cart.add(product=product)

Comment: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id' occurs because product=mes_produits['id'] makes product in this case equal to 1, not just the id attribute

Comment: so how do i fix it

Comment: i'll post an answer with a suggestion of something you could put, but does your cart.add() only want an ID or does it want the whole [id,name,price]?

Comment: yes I want the whole set [id,name,price]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that

```py
def cart_add(request, id):
    dico={"produits":[{'id':1,'name':'pomme de terre','price':1250}]}
    mes_produits=dico['produits']
    cart = Cart(request)
    # sets the product to the first product found with the correct ID 
    # (in case there are duplicates), if none are found set product to None.
    selected_product = next((item for item in mes_produits if item["id"] == id), None)
    if selected_product != None:
        cart.add(product=selected_product) # passes [id,name,price] to cart.add()
    else:
        print("item not found")
    return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html')
```

I haven't tested it but I believe it's the best solution to your problem.